# NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Window

Tags: ngxs, nebular

I have been trying to debug this issue but I have had no success. I believe it's a lack of import of a nebular service or provider but I am not sure which one or where to find it.

my search.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';


import { NgxsModule, Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

import { SearchComponent } from './search.component';
import { NbAutocompleteModule, NbInputModule, NbOverlay, NbOverlayService, NbTriggerStrategyBuilderService, NbWindowService, NB_WINDOW } from '@nebular/theme';
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

describe('SearchComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchComponent>;
  let store: Store;
  let windowMock: NbWindowService = { } as any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SearchComponent ],
      imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([]), HttpClientTestingModule, NbAutocompleteModule, NbInputModule ],
      providers: [ NbWindowService, NbTriggerStrategyBuilderService,
        {provide: NB_WINDOW, useClass: InjectionToken }
        ,
    { provide: NbOverlayService, useClass: NbOverlay }]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    const store:Store = TestBed.inject(Store);
    spyOn(store, 'select').and.returnValue(of(null));
    spyOn(store, 'selectSnapshot').and.returnValue(null);
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();

  });

});
```

my search.component.html

```
<input #autoInput
nbInput
type="text"
(input)="onChange()"
placeholder="Search for companies"
[nbAutocomplete]="auto"
class= "search__input" />




<nb-autocomplete #auto (selectedChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">

  <nb-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="option">
    {{ option }}
  </nb-option>

</nb-autocomplete>
```

It's the bog-standard search component provided by nebular https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/autocomplete/overview#nbautocompletedirective

```
SearchComponent > should create
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InjectionToken Window -> InjectionToken Window]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Window!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'InjectionToken Window', 'InjectionToken Window' ] })
    at <Jasmine>
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:63217/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:915:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:63217/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11081:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:63217/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11081:1)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:63217/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:24198:1)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:63217/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:22101:1)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (http://localhost:63217/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3921:1)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (http://localhost:63217/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:13752:1)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.NbMenuComponent_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:63217/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@nebular/theme/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/index.js:9693:120)
    at getNodeInjectable (http://localhost:63217/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:4029:1)
    at instantiateRootComponent (http://localhost:63217/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:7825:1)
```

Comment: Looks like it's needing the window object, not the NB_WINDOW. You know like the browser window. ie `@Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window` `export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken<Window>('window', {
  factory: () => window,
  providedIn: 'root',
});`

Comment: Where do I add that in the test?

Comment: Really not sure, does nebular have any test harnesses?

Comment: Sadly, it does not.